# snap node to grid in PowerPoint

Tags: vba, powerpoint

In Powerpoint, when creating or node-editing a freeform shape, there is no way to make nodes snap to the grid. To solve this problem I have written a macro to snap the nodes of a selected shape to the grid:

```
Dim oShp As Shape
Dim NodeIndex As Integer
Dim GD, pWidth, pHeight, currxValue, curryValue, xOffset, yOffset As Single

If Not ActiveWindow.Selection.Type = ppSelectionShapes Then Exit Sub
If Not ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Count = 1 Then Exit Sub
If Not ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Type = msoFreeform Then Exit Sub

Set oShp = ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1)

GD = ActivePresentation.GridDistance
pWidth = ActivePresentation.PageSetup.SlideWidth
pHeight = ActivePresentation.PageSetup.SlideHeight

With oShp
    For NodeIndex = .Nodes.Count To 1 Step -1
        pointsArray = .Nodes.Item(NodeIndex).Points
        currxValue = pointsArray(1, 1)
        curryValue = pointsArray(1, 2)
        xOffset = (pWidth / 2) - (Int((pWidth / 2) / GD) * GD)
        yOffset = (pHeight / 2) - (Int((pHeight / 2) / GD) * GD)
        .Nodes.SetPosition Index:=NodeIndex, _
            X1:=Round((currxValue - xOffset) / GD) * GD + xOffset, _
            Y1:=Round((curryValue - yOffset) / GD) * GD + yOffset
    Next

End With
```

My problem is that for a freeform shape with more than about 30 nodes, the macro begins to run very slowly. If the shape contains even more nodes, PowerPoint hangs for quite a while, then the macro fails.

I would be very grateful if anyone can see what I have done wrong or what could be improved/optimized.

Many thanks and best wishes.

Comment: What is it doing when it's running so slowly?  (Use **F8** to step through the code to find out.)  What does it do when it fails? Errors? Where?  How is this called? An event or where?  If you have a ***specific*** problem please [edit] to add detail about it,  If not, then this question is probably better suited to SE [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).   Also see [Debugging VBA](http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/DebuggingVBA.aspx) as well as "[mcve]" and the [help/on-topic].

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. For clarification, the code seems to work fine if I step through it with F8, though the egg-timer does show for a fraction of a second every time I go through the for next loop. When I run the code normally for a shape with about 1000 nodes, PowerPoint goes grey for about one minute, then I get the error: Run-time error: '-2147467259 (80004005)' Method SetPosition of object 'ShapeNodes' failed. The debugger highlights the line beginning: .Nodes.SetPosition

Comment: Okay, so its definitely the .Nodes.SetPosition line. I commented it out and the macro runs instantly on a 1000+ node shape. I know that with Excel VBA the biggest bottleneck is when the code communicates with the sheet. I suppose this may be something similar. I wonder if there is a way to move all the nodes simultaneously rather than individually...?